How to Progromatically Determine when Azure Open AI Finds no Results in Indexed Documents
When using Azure Open AI and Azure Search service with an index of documents as configured in the "bring your own data" example. How can you programmatically determine if the API call successfully found an answer?
The problem is the returned "not found" message is AI generated so I can not string match it e.g. it can very from "The requested information is not available in the retrieved data" or "The retrieved documents did not contain the requested information" etc...
I have also tried counting the number of Citations on the returned message result but a message with a "not found" result can still contain multiple citations.
So how can I programmatically check if the API call successfully found an answer?

In the prompt, tell it exactly what you want it to do. For example 'If no citations are found, reply using these exact words: "Not found". Do not add aything to this message.' I have found this approach to specifying output to be very effective, though you might need to modify the prompt to make it even stronger if it sometimes slips up.

I tried the "Not Found" method by @Lee-xp. It works in most cases, but it does slips up sometimes - which works for me. But if you need 100% accuracy, I guess you can pass the output through another function to measure semantic similarity  (cosine/jaccard similairty) with some of the recorded message and filter based on threshold instead of direct string match.

@user3503711 what responses were you getting when it slipped up?

@Lee-xp It was giving the default response like OP is seeing. "The requested information  is not found..."

@user3503711 To make it stronger add something like 'In the event that no citations are found, you must never say anathying more than the words "Not found"'. Two more things, in cases like this I usually set the temperature to zero, so as to get consistent results. If this still occasionally fails, try 'In the case where not citations found, simply respond: "***** '. You could also tell it to preface all finds with '+++' and all no find responses with '---'. Finally , give some examples of how it should respond: user: ... assistant: ... etc. As a last resort, search for variants of 'not found'

It is a problem when using Azure Open AI and Azure Search service with an index of documents as configured in the "bring your own data" example: it is doing an "all-in-one" call to Azure OpenAI, which is in charge of calling your Azure AI Search resource.
This "all-in-one" call has several drawbacks:

you will see that it is not correctly considering correctly the system message: even if you specify to do specific processing when no matching documents are found, or to reply in a specific language, it's not always taken into account (I would rather say it's not taken into account at all)
this API call is using bad practices in terms of security: if you check the API call payload, you will see that it sends the AI Search resource admin key in it!

In my projects, I tend to avoid using this "all-in-one" call and split it into 2 pieces: the AI Search call and then (when documents are found) the GPT model rephrasing using the search results
